# Java - How do i find out that a string is in the correct format using pattern matching

Tags: java, string, datetime, time, timeofday

My string value;

`09:00-10:00,12:00-14:30,16:00-18:00` (this string repeats time intervals n times like this)

and I want to find out that a string is in the correct format using pattern matching;

```
Pattern.matches("<Pattern Here>", stringValue);
```

is it possible?

I tried;

```
Pattern.matches("^[0-9:0-9-0-9:0-9,]+$", value);
```

But doesn't work properly

Comment: "*is it possible?*" - Yes.

Comment: What error are you getting? Be specific. And consider design choices, i.e. splitting the bad data into an array first, then parsing each individually against your pattern.

Comment: Read a tutorial on regular expressions, rather than just guessing.

Comment: What does "correct" mean?

Comment: as @tgdavies pointed out, one could make the argument that the question is ill-defined. If we, for example, factor in [leap seconds (`en.wikipedia.org`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second), the problem might not be solvable through regular expressions.

Comment: Also, does the first time of  a pair need to be before the second? Does a later pair need to be after an earlier pair?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following pattern for any given range of 2 times in the form of 24h clock:

```
private static final String HOURLY_TIME_PATTERN = "([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])";
private static final String TIME_RANGER_PATTERN = HOURLY_TIME_PATTERN + "-" + HOURLY_TIME_PATTERN;
private static final String PATTERN = "^" + TIME_RANGER_PATTERN + "(," + TIME_RANGER_PATTERN + "?)*$";
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PATTERN);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "09:00-10:00,12:00-14:30,16:00-18:00";
    if (pattern.matcher(input).matches()) {
        System.out.println("We have a match!");
    }
}
```

Explanation:

- `HOURLY_TIME_PATTERN` is the pattern required for a single hour in a 24h format (e.g. 16:25)
- TIME_RANGER_PATTERN is the pattern to find a single time range
  (e.g. 16:25-22:50)
- PATTERN - is the pattern that ensure that we have at least 1 time range, and any other time range must be lead by a comma (we can have zero or more of them)

Comment: This would only find a single match, and wouldn't allow multiple values, as stated in the post.

Comment: oh, I though that each of them is separate input :) will fix the pattern

Comment: This regex it pretty complicated now, but it works...

Comment: Some parenthesis can be removed. And since the regex seems to be used only for validation, we could/should make the groups non-capturing. Furthermore, we can define "sub-patterns" through Strings to structure the pattern more, and then construct the final pattern through String concatenation.

Comment: all good suggestions - will update the code again :D

Comment: I tried but still doesn't work. Can u check answer?

Comment: Just updated the answer, and tested on my machine

Comment: Sure thing, I enjoyed playing with Java again, it’s been a while 

Comment: One could split-up all of this even further. [Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/F8J9sb). @YonatanKarp-Rudin feel free to "steal" what you want if you want to add some.

Comment: I Ike the idea but it also feels a bit over engineered

Answer (score 6):

You can check if the string matches the regex, `^(?:(?:\d{2}:\d{2}\-\d{2}:\d{2})(?:,(?!$))?)*$`. Note that you do not need to put starts-with (i.e. `^`) and ends-with (i.e. `$`) when using [`String#matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)).

If the string passes this validation, split the string on `,` and `-` and then use java.time API to validate the individual time strings.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(hasCorrectFormat("09:00-10:00,12:00-14:30,16:00-18:00")); // true
        System.out.println(hasCorrectFormat("09:00-10:00,12:00-1:30,16:00-18:00")); // false -> 1:30 is not in desired
                                                                                    // format
        System.out.println(hasCorrectFormat("09:00-10:00")); // true
        System.out.println(hasCorrectFormat("09:00 10:00")); // false
        System.out.println(hasCorrectFormat("09:00-10:00,09:00 10:00")); // false
        System.out.println(hasCorrectFormat("09:00-10:00-12:00-14:30,16:00-18:00")); // false
        System.out.println(hasCorrectFormat("09:00-10:00,12:00-14:30,16:00-18:00,")); // false
    }

    static boolean hasCorrectFormat(String strTimeRanges) {
        if (!strTimeRanges.matches("(?:(?:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\-\\d{2}:\\d{2})(?:,(?!$))?)*"))
            return false;
        String[] times = strTimeRanges.split("[-,]");
        for (String time : times) {
            try {
                LocalTime.parse(time);
            } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
true
false
true
false
false
false
false
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mGxUbc/1)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

The valuable [comment from Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74539243/java-how-do-i-find-out-that-a-string-is-in-the-correct-format-using-pattern-ma/74539634#comment131582981_74539634) has prompted me to extend my original answer to show how one can use java.time API to compare the times in individual time ranges. I hope this gives enough hints for learners to extend the solution further based on the complexity of the requirements.

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(hasCorrectFormatAndRanges("09:00-10:00,12:00-14:30,16:00-18:00")); // true
        System.out.println(hasCorrectFormatAndRanges("09:00-10:00,12:00-1:30,16:00-18:00")); // false -> 1:30
        System.out.println(hasCorrectFormatAndRanges("10:00-09:00,12:00-14:30,16:00-18:00")); // false -> 10:00-09:00
        System.out.println(hasCorrectFormatAndRanges("09:00-10:00")); // true
        System.out.println(hasCorrectFormatAndRanges("09:00 10:00")); // false
        System.out.println(hasCorrectFormatAndRanges("09:00-10:00,09:00 10:00")); // false
        System.out.println(hasCorrectFormatAndRanges("09:00-10:00-12:00-14:30,16:00-18:00")); // false
        System.out.println(hasCorrectFormatAndRanges("09:00-10:00,12:00-14:30,16:00-18:00,")); // false
    }

    static boolean hasCorrectFormatAndRanges(String strTimeRanges) {
        if (!strTimeRanges.matches("(?:(?:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\-\\d{2}:\\d{2})(?:,(?!$))?)*"))
            return false;
        String[] timeRanges = strTimeRanges.split(",");
        for (String timeRange : timeRanges) {
            String[] times = timeRange.split("-");
            try {
                if (LocalTime.parse(times[1]).isBefore(LocalTime.parse(times[0])))
                    return false;
            } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
true
false
false
true
false
false
false
false
```

Comment: This would not validate that two time values are separated by a `" - "`, and it would not validate that two time values are separate by two other time values with a `", "`. Example: take the 1st (valid) `String` and replace all occurences of `","` with `"-"` or vice-versa. The now invalid format will evaluate to `true`.

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks for taking the time to review this. I have updated the answer to meet this requirement.

Comment: Still not correct. String `"09:00-10:00-12:00-14:30,16:00-18:00"` (notice the `"-"` between `"10:00"` and `"12:00"`) evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Well... now one could argue whether `"09:00-10:00,12:00-14:30,16:00-18:00,"` should be valid or not. One way or another, I'd suggest to update the explanation. The original explanation does not really fit the code anymore.

Comment: @Turing85 As per the question posted, `"09:00-10:00,12:00-14:30,16:00-18:00,"` is not a valid string.

Comment: This allows for further validating that the times come in order if desired. Like.